# Passing param to function in Yii

Tags: yii

I have set this in my main.php file:

```
'params'=>array(
   'TOTAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER'=>'500100'
)
```

I can successfully access the data using Yii::app()->params['TOTAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER']

I would like to pass this as a default to a method like so:

```
public function myMethod($acctNum=Yii::app()->params['TOTAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER']) {
  ...
}
```

This produces the syntax error: unexpected '('.

I can probably create a workaround with something like:

```
public function myMethod($acctNum=null) {
   $acctNum = !isset($acctNum) ? Yii::app()->params['TOTAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER'] : $acctNum;
}
```

But is there an easier way to format the original method to just avoid the syntax error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function inside a parameter list. (Yii::app()) which is, according to your error not allowed in PHP.

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

from http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Your own workaround would be a nice solution.

Comment: np, sorry to give you a no-go

Answer (score 0):

Can you just pass in "500100" as your default value in your function? 
If the parameter value change within your application it is obviously not the right approach. But if it's a constant you can just pass in that value to your function as the default.

Comment: The function will perform a calculation and most of the time will utilize the account defined as a constant, but the application will use alternate accounts on occasion.  That is why I wanted to give the option to override.  Also, the account number may change and I didn't want to hard code it throughout. Thanks.